# Lmfit minimise gives ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3811,) and (7622,)

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, lmfit

I am trying to fit data to a least sq function using python's lmfit. minimize.
This is a reference code i found on python lmfit's website.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import lmfit

x = np.linspace(1, 10, 250)
np.random.seed(0)
y = 3.0 * np.exp(-x / 2) - 5.0 * np.exp(-(x - 0.1) / 10.) + 0.1 * 
np.random.randn(x.size)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.show()

p = lmfit.Parameters()
p.add_many(('a1', 4.), ('a2', 4.), ('t1', 3.), ('t2', 3., True))

def residual(p):
    v = p.valuesdict()
    return v['a1'] * np.exp(-x / v['t1']) + v['a2'] * np.exp(-(x - 
    0.1) / v['t2']) - y

mi = lmfit.minimize(residual, p, method='nelder', nan_policy='omit')
lmfit.printfuncs.report_fit(mi.params, min_correl=0.5)

plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.plot(x, residual(mi.params) + y, 'r', label='best fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

I wrote a similar code with a different defined function but when i try to plot
`plt.plot(x, residual(mi.params) + y, 'r', label='best fit')`
it gives me `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3811,) and (7622,)`
This does not happen in the original code and what i noticed is that `len(residual(mi.params) + y)` is same as `len(residual(mi.params)` in the original code. But in my case the length of `residual(mi.params)` and `len(y)` add up.
I have tried everything but cannot figure out why this is happening.
if anyone knows and can help out, it would be appreciated!

Comment: post *your* code, not the example code you started from. What does "But in my case the length of residual(mi.params) and len(y) add up" mean?  Add up to what?   Is it possible that your data or model have complex values, not strictly real?

Comment: Sorry about that. What i meant is that in the original code if i check for the total items in the list residual(mi.params) + y, that is 250 which is same as that of the individual items in the list i.e. list(residual(mi.params)) and list (y) both also have 250 items in it. however in my case my residual(mi.params) has suppose 300 items and list y has 300 items but my list (residual(mi.params)+y) together gives me 600 items. this does not happen in the original code and i was wondering why that it.

Comment: Post your code. Really, no kidding. Post your code.